# Unable to install a package via cabal - unmet dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal

How can I possible fix this?

```
$ cabal install http-conduit
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: attoparsec-0.13.0.1/installed-5b6... (user goal)
trying: http-conduit-2.1.8 (user goal)
trying: monad-control-1.0.0.5 (dependency of http-conduit-2.1.8)
next goal: conduit (dependency of http-conduit-2.1.8)
rejecting: conduit-1.2.6.1, 1.2.6, 1.2.5.1, 1.2.5, 1.2.4.3, 1.2.4.2, 1.2.4.1,
1.2.4, 1.2.3.1 (conflict: attoparsec =>
transformers==0.5.1.0/installed-426..., conduit => transformers>=0.2.2 &&
<0.5)
rejecting: conduit-1.2.3, 1.2.2.2, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0.2, 1.2.0.1,
1.2.0, 1.1.7, 1.1.6, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1,
1.1.0.2, 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.17.1, 1.0.17, 1.0.16, 1.0.15.1, 1.0.15, 1.0.14,
1.0.13.1, 1.0.13, 1.0.12, 1.0.11.1, 1.0.11, 1.0.10.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.9.3,
1.0.9.2, 1.0.9.1, 1.0.9, 1.0.8, 1.0.7.4, 1.0.7.3, 1.0.7.2, 1.0.7.1, 1.0.7,
1.0.6, 1.0.5.1, 1.0.5, 1.0.4.2, 1.0.4.1, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0.2,
1.0.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.5.6, 0.5.5 (conflict: monad-control==1.0.0.5, conduit =>
monad-control>=0.3.1 && <0.4)
rejecting: conduit-0.5.4.2, 0.5.4.1, 0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2.7, 0.5.2.6, 0.5.2.5,
0.5.2.4, 0.5.2.3, 0.5.2.2, 0.5.2.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.2, 0.4.1.1,
0.4.1, 0.4.0.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.0, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.1.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.0,
0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1.1, 0.0.1, 0.0.0.2, 0.0.0.1, 0.0.0 (conflict:
http-conduit => conduit>=0.5.5 && <1.3)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

And

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.8.0
using version 1.22.7.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: There's conflict between the dependency of  your target `http-conduit-2.1.8` and the already installed `attoparsec-0.13.0.1`, the two are requesting different versions of a package. Read briefly [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/Survival) and try haskell-stack build tool please.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can use haskellstack.org : `stack install http-conduit`.

Comment: Is the version of `transformers` -- 0.5.1.0 -- the one that came with your ghc? If not, something has gone wrong with this sandbox and you should start over. transformers-0.5.x is too new for things to have caught up with. There is also adding `--allow-newer` to force compatibility. But `stack` will be the best plan, I agree.

Comment: @Sibi, is stack an alrenative to cabal?

Comment: @Michael, I've removed sandbox and started again and that didn't help. How would stack help me?

Comment: @AlanCoromano Not exactly, but sort of. Stack uses curated packages by default which are known to build and they avoid this type of problem. I would recommend you going with stack. You can find the the installation details [here](http://haskellstack.org/).

Comment: @AlanCoromano I see that like your version of `transformers`, your version of the `cabal` tool and the `Cabal` library is from the cutting edge. What version of ghc are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that conduit required an older version of transformers than the one at the base of your dependency tree.

Since then, a newer conduit has been uploaded that lifts the upper bound: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.2

Now, if you try the same procedure, things *should* work...